# If A and B are independent events but NOT mutually exclusive, find P(A and B)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have a question about Probability in statistics:

Suppose P(A) = 0.25 and P(B) = 0.15. If A and B are independent events but NOT mutually exclusive, find P(A and B)?

Can somebody teach me how to compute this problem by not providing the answer directly?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a textbook? Somewhere in there should be a concise description of what it means that $A$ and $B$ are independent. (By the way, it's hard for events to be _both_ independent and mutually exclusive.) Do you really mean $P(A \text{ and }B)$ and not $P(A\text{ or } B)$?

Comment: Yes. P(A and B) I looked at my textbook as well, but I can't find an example that's related to this question. that's why im kinda confused :)

Comment: If you need longer explanations than in my answer, you could look up https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two events that are not *mutually exclusive* (another word for *mutually exclusive* is  *disjoint*) can either be *independent* or *dependent*

For *independent* events, to get P(A and B), you simply apply the multiplication principle.

Comment: Not mutually exclusive is also called disjoint?

Comment: No,no, *mutually exclusive* is also called *disjoint*. Editing answer, if sentence has caused confusion.

Comment: What you are saying in your first line is also true for events that are mutually exclusive. So I do not see the use of that remark. It can even be misleading (making the OP believe that is a condition).

Comment: I have made an assertion only about the type of events under discussion, viz. those that are not mutually exclusive. The idea of the sentence was to hint that some other treatment has to be given for dependent events.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are independent events, they cannot be mutually exclusive, can they ?

So the general rule for computing the probability of the joint occurrence of independent events can be used.

Do you need more hints ?

Comment: "Since they are independent events, they cannot be mutually exclusive, can they ?" As I said in my comment above, it's uncommon, but not impossible (let them both be events that cannot happen).

Comment: @Arthur I agree with your comment, of course, since $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ (defining independence) is true if one  of the events is impossible. In this instance, obviously, neither event is impossible but my statement is not precise enough. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @Arthur: Aren't mutually exclusive independent events just a mathematical oddity of no practical significance, since you may not be able to compute both conditional probabilities, and $P(A\cap B)$ is always $0$, regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are independent or not.