# Probability of two independent events both occurring $P(A\cap B)$, if $P( A )$ and $P( B|A )$ are known?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My ultimate goal is to answer this question: what are the odds that *three* state licensing boards each made a mistake by licensing an applicant as a psychologist, when they actually should not have done so because the psychologist did not meet an education and training requirement?

But I will start with the same question concerning *two* licensing boards so that I don't get myself confused.  :O/

$P(A)$ = Probability that Maryland *mistakenly* licenses a psychologist. The mistake is due to an error checking credentials.

$P(B)$ = Probability that Virginia *mistakenly* licenses the same psychologist. Virginia's mistake is also due to an error checking credentials.

$A$ and $B$ are *independent* events.

However, if Maryland makes a mistake, *we assume for this hypothetical* that the error is due to **complexity** in the applicant's education and training documentation.

Consequently, if Maryland makes a mistake and licenses a psychologist they shouldn't have licensed, then Virginia is more likely to make an error too *because of the complexity* in the applicant's education and training documentation.

For this hypothetical, we will assume that:

$P(B|A) = 0.2$.

The probability of Virginia making an error, given that Maryland made an error, is $0.2$, *not* because the Maryland decision influences the Virginia decision (it doesn't), but because we know (in this hypothetical scenario) that the applicant's education and training documentation is more complex than usual, and therefore more prone to error.

Given these hypothetical facts: What is the probability that *both* Maryland and Virginia will make mistakes and license a psychologist who should not have been licensed?

I *think* the answer is: $P(A ∩ B) = P(A) P(B|A) = (0.05)(0.20) = 0.01$.

Is there a flaw in my reasoning? In my calculation? What else is important for me to know?

TIA,

Mark

P.S. I searched math.stackexchange.com for various terms and found two somewhat related questions with answers, which I read:

[Why P(B|A) is not the same as P(A∩B) if both A & B are independent events?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432773/why-pba-is-not-the-same-as-pa%E2%88%A9b-if-both-a-b-are-independent-events)

[If A and B are independent events but NOT mutually exclusive, find P(A and B)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477859/if-a-and-b-are-independent-events-but-not-mutually-exclusive-find-pa-and-b)

There are other questions with answers that are probably related, but they all use some sort of programming or spreadsheet notation that I don't understand.

Comment: The formula $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\cdot\mathbb P(B\mid A)$ holds always -- in fact, it's practically the definition of conditional probability. So your calculation is correct.

Comment: A point worth making explicit: when we say that two events $A$ and $B$ are independent, we mean that $\mathbb P(B\mid A)=\mathbb P(B)$, i.e. $A$ occuring doesn't affect the probability of $B$. From a purely mathematical perspective, we don't really care about causality or whatnot. By the formula above, this is often expressed as $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\cdot\mathbb P(B)$.

Comment: Your description somewhat contradicts the assumption of independence.  The credentials difficulty could be the same for both states.

Comment: Thank you jlammy - much appreciated! // herb steinberg - Ah, excellent point. I will do some more reading on dependent events. Thank you.